# Thousand Separator and Numeric Only in Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have both a thousand separator and numeric-only textbox in my web page. I've tried many things, from around the web with no success.
Here is my code:

```
$(".price").keydown(function (e) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
            if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        $(".price").keyup(function (e) {
            num = $(this).val().replace(',', '');
            // separate the whole number and the fraction if possible
            var sep = ",";
            var decpoint = ".";
            a = num.split(decpoint);
            x = a[0]; // decimal
            y = a[1]; // fraction
            z = "";


            if (typeof (x) != "undefined") {
                // reverse the digits. regexp works from left to right.
                for (i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    z += x.charAt(i);
                // add seperators. but undo the trailing one, if there
                z = z.replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1" + sep);
                if (z.slice(-sep.length) == sep)
                    z = z.slice(0, -sep.length);
                x = "";
                // reverse again to get back the number
                for (i = z.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    x += z.charAt(i);
                // add the fraction back in, if it was there
                if (typeof (y) != "undefined" && y.length > 0)
                    x += decpoint + y;
            }
            $(this).val(x);
        });
```

In this code I'm mixing two solutions. One for the separator, and another one for numeric-only. Can someone help me fix this please?

Comment: what the issue you faced? Whether you want both in same action?

Comment: @Siva.G, it doesn't work correctly.